# Simulink get name/label of a port programmatically

Tags: matlab, simulink

In my model I've a `Delay` block (see image below) connected with other blocks (not shown in the image). I have handles of each of the three ports of the `Delay` block, but I do not know which handle belongs to which port. Is there a programmatic way to get the "name" of the ports (e.g. Getting the values `u`, `d` and `x0`)?

I have access to the block's handle and handles of the three ports as well.

Please note that the labels `u`, `d` and `x0` as shown in the picture are provided by Simulink, not me. And I do not want to put custom labels/tags to the ports.

[image]

Comment: Try `get(port_handle)` in the interactive REPL, you'll get a list of all the attributes.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks. I could not find it using your approach.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
get(find_system(gcb,'FindAll','On','SearchDepth',1,'BlockType','Inport'),'Name');
```

This will give you port names of Subsystem.

Instead of gcb you can put your subsystem path 'ModelName/SubsystemName'